# I don't know how her notebook is in my bag

Tags: word-usage

A girl was looking for her notebook.  Someone had stolen it.  So the teacher was searching everyone's bags.  So the notebook was found in a girl's notebook.  She replied:

> I don't know how her notebook is in my bag.

Does it sound natural?  Are there more natural ways of expressing this?

Answer (score 2):

I presume she meant something along the lines of:

> I don't know how her notebook got in my bag.

Adding "got" makes it sound more natural to me.

Alternatively:

> I don't know why her notebook is in my bag

(why instead of how)

Comment: Note: Saying "how... got" is less formal and a little humorous, because it gives the notebook some agency.  Saying "why... is" is the more formal way of saying this.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanetyeah true, I did think it make sit sound more humorous as well. But since the OP asked for 'natural' and not explicitly formal, it sounds okay to me :)